# Google places api not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement the autocomplete feature of google places api in a text field. Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { initialize(){

  var input = document.getElementById('location_input');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        alert(place.geometry.location.lat());
        alert(place.geometry.location.lng());
    });
}
});
</script>

<form role="search" method="get" action="http://elearningwp.thimpress.com/">
   <span class="location_placeholder ml5">
       <i class="location arrow icon tiny pr2"></i>
       <input id="location_input" role="combobox" aria-labelledby="label_search_location"
                                           aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="explore-location-suggest" 
                                           placeholder="Please type a location..." class="dark" style="width:280px;">
    </span>

     <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="What do you want to learn today?" class="form-control courses-search-input" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="hidden" value="course" name="ref">
     <button type="submit" style="width:150px;margin-right: -90px; float: right;"><i class="fa fa-search">Search</i></button>
     <span class="widget-search-close"></span>
</form>
```

But the code doesn't seem to work. If I try the code in a separate file though it works beautifully. Here is that code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
 google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        alert(place.geometry.location.lat());
        alert(place.geometry.location.lng());
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
<button id="btn" type="button">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can notice instead of using `$(document).ready(function() { initialize(){` here I am using `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

Here is a snapshot of the result:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: @deceze any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is very common. You can check it in the console:

[image]

This error means that it is a bit strange to 'define' the initialize function inside your anonymous function without declaration. Your jQuery's method may looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  var input = document.getElementById('location_input');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        alert(place.geometry.location.lat());
        alert(place.geometry.location.lng());
    });

});
```

And your complete code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

  var input = document.getElementById('location_input');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        alert(place.geometry.location.lat());
        alert(place.geometry.location.lng());
    });

});
</script>

<form role="search" method="get" action="http://elearningwp.thimpress.com/">
   <span class="location_placeholder ml5">
       <i class="location arrow icon tiny pr2"></i>
       <input id="location_input" role="combobox" aria-labelledby="label_search_location"
                                           aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="explore-location-suggest" 
                                           placeholder="Please type a location..." class="dark" style="width:280px;">
    </span>

     <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="What do you want to learn today?" class="form-control courses-search-input" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="hidden" value="course" name="ref">
     <button type="submit" style="width:150px;margin-right: -90px; float: right;"><i class="fa fa-search">Search</i></button>
     <span class="widget-search-close"></span>
</form>
```